# sequelize doesn't connect to MySql

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, orm, sequelize.js

Sequlize throws an error while applying migrations.

```
# sequelize --config config/config.js -m
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Unable to connect to database: Error: Failed to authenticate for MySQL. Please double check your settings.
```

Config.js

```
"db": {
"development": {
  "username": "imvgm_dev",
  "password": "imvgm_dev",
  "database": "imvgm_development",
  "host": "localhost"
},
"production": {
  "username": "imvgm_production",
  "password": "imvgm_production",
  "database": "imvgm_production",
  "host": "localhost"
},
"testing": {
  "username": "imvgm_testing",
  "password": "imvgm_testing",
  "database": "imvgm_testing",
  "host": "localhost"
}
```

I can easily connect to db through

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=imvgm_dev --password=imvgm_dev imvgm_development
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add "port" to your config.js.
And you need not specify config.js in the command line. This should work:

```
# sequelize -m
```